# use a variable in JSON.stringify

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, stringify

I use stringify in my node restful server to provide data:

```
answer = JSON.stringify({activities: result}, null, '\t');
return answer
```

where result is a js object;
i receive the correct output for this:

```
{
"activities": [
    {
     "id": 1,
     "title": aaa
    },
    { 
     "id": 2,
     "title": bbb
    }
  ]
}
```

but now i would like to use a variable instead of a fixed string in the left part of stringify function; something like:

```
var name = "activities";
answer = JSON.stringify({name: result}, null, '\t');
```

this doesn't work, because name becomes a fixed string in the stringified object

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to build an object using indexer notation:

```
var name = ...;
var obj = {};
obj[name] = something;
```

Comment: With ES6, you can do it inside the object literal assignment, like `{ [name]: something }`

Comment: write the answer in syntax of the question for the user readability.

Answer (score 6):

If you want JSON.stringify() Object then try this:

```
var field = "my_field_name";

var obj = {};

obj[field] = value;

var myJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `new` with an anonymous function to do it as well:

```
answer = JSON.stringify(new function(){ this[name] = result; }, null, '\t');
```